# "The applicability of the algorithm to uniform filter bank" or "to the uniform filter bank"?

Tags: definite-articles, determiners

I have this sentence:

> We would like to prove the applicability of the algorithm to uniform filter bank.

I am not sure about *the* before *uniform filter bank*. To give the context for the sentence, I would like to say here that the algorithm is applicable to any uniform filter bank.

Answer (score 4):

*Uniform filter bank* is just a name; in this context, it requires a *determiner*, which pins down which holders of the name are involved. The determiner may be an article, a possessive or demonstrative adjective, or a quantifier. What determiner you employ depends on what exactly you mean. In this case, you have actually defined it in your question:

> We would like to prove the applicability ... to **any** uniform filter bank.

You could also say

> We would like to prove the applicability ... to **all** uniform filter bank**s**.

In other circumstances you might have meant:

> We would like to prove the applicability ... to **many** uniform filter banks.
>   We would like to prove the applicability ... to **some** uniform filter banks.
>   We would like to prove the applicability ... to **these** uniform filter banks.

And so forth... In some circumstances, another part of the sentence may act as a determiner through contrast. For instance, if you have already proved that the algorithm is applicable to non-uniform filter banks, you might then proceed:

> We would now like to prove the applicability ... to **uniform** filter banks.

Answer (score 0):

The way it stands, the sentence makes me think that you are attempting to convince uniform filter banks that the algorithm is applicable to them. At the very least, it can be read that way. You could avoid that using *on*

> We would like to prove the applicability ... **on** uniform filter banks.

Of course, a method can or cannot be applied *to* a problem not *on* it. Applying it *on* makes one think of make up.

So, to remove ambiguity and make it easier to read, I would go for:

> We would like to prove that the algorithm can be applied to uniform filter banks.

In any case, while a perfectly good word which you can find in dictionaries,  *applicability* still makes me cringe for some reason. I would tend to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with OP's use of the preposition **to** here, [as attested by](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=applicability%20of%20this%20concept%20to&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

But in the absence of a determiner (*a, the, some, all, many,* etc.) before it, *uniform filter **banks*** needs to be in the plural. By default, if no determiner is given, it effectively means *all, any* UFB's.